# Setting up Subversion repo using LDAP groups in svn_access_file

Tags: svn, httpd.conf

If I was doing this from scratch, I would have made this two separate repositories. Unfortunately, I have to make do with what is there.

Our repository looks like this:

```
/trunk
/tags
/branches
/secret/trunk
/secret/tags
/secret/branches
```

I have my SVN configuration setup like this:

```
<Location /gorp>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /mnt/svn/repositories/gorp
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Vegicorp Repostitory"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldap.vegicorp.net:389/DC=vegicorp,DC=NET?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldap-read,,OU=Users,OU=vegicorp,DC=vegicorp,DC=net"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword swordfish
    Require ldap-group CN=Development,OU=Groups,OU=vegicorp,DC=vegicorp,DC=net
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/repos_path_access/gorp
</Location>
```

This works great. All users in the LDAP group `Development` has access to our repository. However, not all developers should be able to even see the `secret` directory. Instead, I only want users in the `cabal` LDAP group to be able to access it.

And, I have my file `gorp` under the above `repos_path_access` access directory look like this:

```
[/]
* = r

[/trunk]
* = rw

[/branches]
* = rw

[/tags]
* = rw

[/secret]
dvadar = rw
cpalpatine = rw
glucas = rw
* =
```

So far, so good. My `cabal` group users, `dvadar`, `cpalpatine`, and `glucas`, have access to the `/secret` directory in my repository, and no one else even sees it. However, as people come and go, I have to manually change this path based access file. What I would like to do is have my path-based access give everyone in `cabal` access and hide it for everyone else:

```
[/]
* = r

[/trunk]
* = rw

[/branches]
* = rw

[/tags]
* = rw

[/secret]
@cabal = rw
* =
```

This does not work. Instead, I see this in my logs:

```
Tue Sep 03 11:30:50 2013] [error] [client 10.55.9.217] \
Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: An authz rule refers to group '@cabal'
```

What is the best way to give my `cabal` group access to `secret` without the rest of my developers seeing this directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious way:

Define cabal group members in AuthzSVNAccessFile.

- You can do it by hand (edit members every time, when membership change)
- You can find and use LDAP-to-Authz sync-script (mentioned here, on SO somewhere) for updating `@cabal` when `CN=cabal` changed in LDAP

Tricky way

- You can add additional `<Location /gorp/secret>` with changed `Require ldap-group` directive and maintain group entirely in LDAP

Comment: I knew I could write a LDAP to Authz syncscript, but I was hoping there was some httpd configuration that could handle this. The _tricky way_ is intriguing though.

Comment: Some information on a script which does the sync: http://thoughtspark.org/2009/01/20/using-ldap-groups-with-subversion-s-authz-file/

Answer (score -1):

I have something very similar to your question which should fully answer it:

```
@ZTE_OHSAS_administrators = rw
~@ZTE_OHSAS_administrators =
```

That one should work

¡Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I didn't find any of the current projects for syncing SVN authz with LDAP working satisfactory so I created a new one.

It's available here:
https://github.com/rbw0/authzync

And yes, I'm aware this is an old post. But users searching for a solution to this are likely to end up here.

Comment: Generally you should include the relevant code here rather than linking to a repo.

Comment: Repository is no longer available. This reference should be updated or removed.