# SVN Path based authorization for AD groups

Tags: svn, active-directory, authorization

Our production SVN server is configured to not allow Anonymous access and users are always authenticated against our AD groups.

Currently, any authenticated user can read and write to the entire repo. We would like to now restrict write access to certain parts of the SVN tree.
This is not a problem of not trusting our team, it is an external audit requirement and we have to comply.

Based on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html we can only specify a list of individual users within the access control file. Instead of maintaining a long list of users within this file, we would like to simply create new AD group and mention the AD group name within this file. This way control over who gets to be part of the group is external to SVN and we don't have to keep on modifying this file every time people are added or removed. Is there a way this can be done by specifying a list of AD groups instead of user lists?

We are using SVN 1.9.5, Apache 2.2.32 (Win64) and Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: FYI: VisualSVN Server supports path-based authorization for AD groups out of the box.

Comment: @bahrep - it must be answer in order to: 1) Give you fair `+1` into rep 2) *Easy* get permanent URL for future referencing (at least I can forget fact, but will have tagged URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You **can** use (local) groups inside acl-file
2. You can't use|refer to LDAP|AD groups inside acl-file https://stackoverflow.com/a/18598547/960558

Thus, @bahrep suggested really **The Best Thing (tm)**

Comment: Thank you. We don't use VisualSVN currently. For now I guess, we'll have to create local groups within the ACL file and specify individual user lists and then may be look into implementing VisualSVN as a long term change.